# Android calling activities after boot? Lifecycle of activities, BroadcastReceivers.

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, lifecycle, boot

So I'm having an application with one Activity that does nothing and two Classes that extend BroadcastReceiver, but those are never registered anywhere.

The app has the permission

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

but apart from that nothing is ever "started". 
Nevertheless the application shows up in the threads/ processes in Eclipse's LogCat after boot and the BroadcastReceivers receive the intents that they filter for.

- Does Android start every installed app in the background? Why is my app started after boot? - Are BroadcastReceivers active although they were not registered?

I couldnt find anything official for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app starts after boot up is because of the permission

Not every app had this character except for those in which this permission is added

Comment: And the BroadcastReceivers are started without explicitly registering them in an Activity?